# How to save a screenshot of what's on the OpenGL viewer?

Tags: c#, opengl

How to save a screenshot of what's on the OpenGL viewer like printscreen and save it as a bitmap object or picture using c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[glReadPixels()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) is your best bet.  Not sure about C#, but most of the GDI stuff I've done needs pixel data in BGR, not RGB, so keep that in mind.